# MAC-IP reservation is not working

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, router, lan, ip-address

I'm trying to assign my laptop the same IP address every time it connects to my home LAN (192.168.1.52). I log in to my router (Netgear), go to LAN Settings and **Add** a new IP reservation.

I enter my MAC address, obtained from `ifconfig` and matching the list of available MAC addresses in the table above this page's form (so I am **confident** its the correct MAC), and give it a desired IP address of 192.168.1.52. I copy-n-paste the device name from the table above into the Machine name field on the form.  I click submit.

I then log out of the router, disconnect from the wireless LAN and then reconnect.

I run `ifconfig` again - DHCP has kicked in and my IP address is 192.168.1.5.

What am I doing wrong here?!? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also make sure you didn't accidentally put your wired Ethernet interface's MAC address.  You also may need to restart your router for that to take effect.

Comment: No I'm just a huge dummy and @ultrasawblade was correct. I didn't restrict my DHCP pool from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.51 (the first 50), so it looks like DHCP was overriding the IP reservation. Once I added this restriction, applied changes and reconnected to the LAN, I'm now given 192.168.1.52 like I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I have an (older) Netgear modem/router that I just tested, and it simply does not seem to care if the reserved address is in or out of the DHCP pool of dynamic addresses.  But a 1 year old Netgear wireless router will not even accept a reserved address that is outside the DHCP range.  So your experience makes a 3rd variation of how Netgear products handle reserved IP addresses.